# updating the range of iterator in for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on for loop where in I am using two data frame. Length of `df1` is `10000` and that of `df2` is `1`. With in the `for loop` I am updating `df2` data frame. However while in execution my code is taking df2 length as 1 only. Is there any way possible where the for loop can take the updated length of df2.

```
for i, j in itertools.product(range(len(df1)), range(len(df2))):
..
..
```

Alternate solution I have used is using two for loops for each data frames, but that is taking lot of time for execution.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish with this `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, can you clearify your question?  it seems like you are trying to hit all of the possible permutations in two lists (data frames). In this case your time complexity is going to end up as m * n no matter what approach that you take.  

Oh, and jjramsey, I love the xy problem page. This harks back to a common refrain in my developer days... What are you _trying_ to do.